# How to inject different subclasses as ManagedProperty JSF 2?

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2, managed-bean

I'm new to JSF and I'm wondering if it's possible to inject different subclasses of a base class as a MangedProperty, depending on different situations? For instance, I have this managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Claim implements Serializable {
    private Loss lossDetails; //need to inject one of two subclasses
}
```

And the following base class:

```
public class Loss implements Serializable {
    private String lossCause;
    private String lossDescription;
}
```

Which has two subclasses:

```
public class AutoLoss extends Loss implements Serializable {
    private List<String> vehicles;
    //...
}

public class PropLoss extends Loss implements Serializable {
    private String property;
    private boolean weatherRelated;
    //...
}
```

Depending on selections that are made on my application's JSF pages, I want to inject one of the subclasses as the `lossDetails` ManagedProperty in the `Claim` managed bean. Since I can't give the two subclasses the same managed bean name and I don't know ahead of time which one needs to be injected, is this something that can be accomplished in JSF? Or is there a different approach I should be considering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't.

- It's not possible to inject a request scoped value as managed property in a session scoped bean.
- Entities should not be treated as managed beans.

Rather pass it as method argument instead:

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{lossManager.losses}" var="loss">
    <h:column>
        <h:commandButton value="Claim" action="#{claim.doAction(loss)}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

With in `Claim` managed bean:

```java
public void doAction(Loss loss) {
    // ...
}
```