# ViewScoped bean extending another ViewScopedBean

Tags: jsf, subclass, cdi, view-scope

I am using JSF 2.3.
Is it possible to have a ViewScoped bean extending another ViewScopedBean (using CDI or whatever)? In the xhtml template I would like to refer to any of both ViewScoped beans depending on some condition (i.e. user privileges)

Comment: How was the answer of Nikos on your previous question unclear? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74134127

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but in the question specified both session scoped beans are not referred by a xhtml template. In my current situation though, I should have one xhtmt template, in which sometimes the one, sometimes the other ViewScoped beans shoul be referred. So I am not sure if that is possible, and what shall the behaviour be in that case

Comment: Just use `#{theOne}` in view? (based on exact code in answer of Nikos)